# Why mustn't a jwt id token be used for authentication on a backend?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0

I'm implementing oauth2 with JWTs for a SPA + backend server that uses Auth0 as my Idp. I've followed the Auth0 documentation and arrived at a solution where my SPA sends the id token it receives from the Idp to the server as a Bearer token in the Authorization header. The server gets the public key from the jwks and verifies the token before responding with any data. This works and I believe it's secure. But in the comments of this [blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/navigating-rs256-and-jwks/) the author states "this token [the id_token] must not be used for authentication on a backend)".

Why mustn't a jwt id token be used for authentication on a backend?